# Can I slice a numpy array using an array as indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, slice, matrix-indexing

I have 2 numpy arrays:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])

b = np.array([2, 1, 2])
```

I want to use `b` as starting indices into the columns of `a` and set all the values of `a` from those column indexes onwards to 0 like this:

```
np.array([[1, 2, 3],
          [4, 0, 6],
          [0, 0, 0]])
```

i.e., set elements of column 1 from position 2 onwards to 0, set elements of column 2 from position 1 onwards to 0, and set elements of column 3 from position 2 onwards to 0.

When I try this:

```
a[:, b:] = 0
```

I get

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Is there a way to slice using an array of indices without a for loop?

Edit: updated the example to show the indices can be arbitrary

Comment: I don't understand why `a[:, b:] = 0` and not `a[:, b] = 0` (all rows and columns specified by b)?

Comment: Do you understand the error.  In `[x:]` (a slice)`x` can only be an integer, not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [boolean array indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). First, create a mask of indices you want to set to 0 and then apply the mask to array and assign the replacement value (e.g., 0 in your case).

```
mask = b>np.arange(a.shape[1])[:,None]
a[~mask]=0
```

output:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: good use case of broadcasting. Alternatively, we can generate the exact boolean mask with `bmask = b<=np.arange(a.shape[1])[:,None]`, so we can avoid the mask negation. One less operation in terms of compute.

Comment: @kmario23 yeah, I thought about it first but then thought this way is more educating. Thank you for the comment and edit.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is in `a[:,b:]`; here `b:` means little if `b` is not a scaler e.g. `5:` means 6th onwards but `[1,2,3]:` means nothing when array is 2d.

It should be `a[:,b]`. Setting `a[:,b] = 0` will set all columns specified in `b` to `0`. Following is the run.

```py
In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
   ...:               [4, 5, 6],
   ...:               [7, 8, 9]])
   ...: 
   ...: b = np.array([2, 1, 2])
   ...: 

In [4]: a
Out[4]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])

In [5]: b
Out[5]: array([2, 1, 2])

In [6]: b.dtype
Out[6]: dtype('int64')

In [7]: a[:, b:] = 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-6e5050513225> in <module>
----> 1 a[:, b:] = 0

TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

In [8]: a[:, b] = 0

In [9]: a
Out[9]: 
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [4, 0, 0],
       [7, 0, 0]])
```

But that's not what you want.

To get what you want, you need to specify rows indices and column indices e.g. `(1,1), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)`.

```py
In [11]: a[[1,2,2,2], [1, 0, 1,2]] = 0

In [12]: a
Out[12]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 0, 6],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Sorry, my example was too simple. I updated it to show the indices can be arbitrary.